# Sequence "TAB_SEQ" not found; SQL statement: select nextval ('tab_seq') [90036-193]

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, testcontainers

During integration tests, when I try to save an entity, I catch an error. However, I use posgresql and I checked the sequence created at the time of database initialization. I do not see such an error when launching the application. only at the time of the test run.

```sql
create sequence if not exists tab_seq;
create table if not exists tab
(
    id  bigint not null. primary key,

.....
);
```

```java
....
@Testcontainers
class DateTest {


    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;
  
    @Container
    public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:12.7")
            .withReuse(true)
            .withInitScript("sql/create_table.sql")
            .withDatabaseName("db");

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void configureProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {

        registry.add("source.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("source.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("source.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer::getPassword);
    }
```

```java
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager(HikariDataSource dataSource) {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.client"
        );

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tab", schema = "public")
public class ClientEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "tab_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "tab_seq", sequenceName = "tab_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id
```

I noticed that for some reason, the custom properties that were defined for the container via **@DynamicPropertySource** do not come here, so the built-in **H2** db is taken as the configuration.

```java
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "source.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dbProps() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
```

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Sequence "TAB_SEQ" not found; SQL statement:
> select nextval ('tab_seq') [90036-193]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)

Who has any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?